# how to create a permanent change from an if statement?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to python and coding in general so please excuse me if my code is messy or unorganized.  I'm creating a battleship game and have established a hit system (white for a correct guess, red for an incorrect guess), however, I cannot seem to make the changes permanent, I would like for when the space button is pressed the colour and block of your guess stays in that coordinate.

The controls are WASD to move and SPACE to fire.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1050, 550))  # set display to a size of 1000x500 pixels

pygame.display.set_caption("Battleships")  # name this screen "Battleships"


# colours
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (200, 0, 0)
green = (0, 200, 0)
bright_red = (255, 0, 0)
bright_green = (0, 255, 0)
shiptestcolour = (0, 50, 255)
shipfinalcolour = (0, 200, 255)
# fonts
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('arial bold', 30)
textsurface1 = myfont.render('Your score: ', False, (0, 255, 0))  # add in score keeping variable
textsurface2 = myfont.render('Enemy score: ', False, (0, 255, 0))
textsurface3 = myfont.render('A      B      C      D      E      F      G      H      I      J', False, black)

enemyship_listx = [50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500]
enemyship_listy = [50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500]

randomnum1=(random.randint(0, 8))
randomnum2=(random.randint(0, 8))
randomnum3=(random.randint(0, 8))
randomnum4=(random.randint(0, 7))
randomnum5=(random.randint(0, 8))
randomnum6=(random.randint(0, 6))
randomnum7=(random.randint(0, 8))
randomnum8=(random.randint(0, 8))
randomnum9=(random.randint(0, 6))
randomnum10=(random.randint(0, 8))
randomnum11=(random.randint(0, 6))
randomnum12=(random.randint(0, 8))

ship1smallx = enemyship_listx[randomnum1]
ship1smally = enemyship_listy[randomnum2]
ship2mediumx = enemyship_listx[randomnum3]
ship2mediumy = enemyship_listy[randomnum4]
ship3largex = enemyship_listx[randomnum5]
ship3largey = enemyship_listy[randomnum6]
ship4largex = enemyship_listx[randomnum7]
ship4largey = enemyship_listy[randomnum8]
ship5mediumx = enemyship_listx[randomnum9]
ship5mediumy = enemyship_listy[randomnum10]
ship6smallx = enemyship_listx[randomnum11]
ship6smally = enemyship_listy[randomnum12]

enemyship_listx = [50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500]
enemyship_listy = [50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500]

shipxcoor= [ship1smallx, ship2mediumx, ship3largex, ship4largex, ship5mediumx, ship6smallx]
shipycoor= [ship1smally, ship2mediumy, ship3largey, ship4largey, ship5mediumy, ship6smally ]

hitcoorx = [50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500]
hitcoory = [50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500]

x = 0 #x used for x axis not to be confused with other x axis variables
y = 0 #y is used for y axis not to be confused with other y axis variables

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # when the player presses the Exit button in the top right the window will close
            run = False

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x>0:
        x = x - 1
        hitcoorx[x]
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 9:
        x = x + 1
        hitcoorx[x]
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and y >0:
        y = y - 1
        hitcoory[x]
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and y< 9:
        y = y + 1
        hitcoory[y]

    win.fill(shipfinalcolour)

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 100, 255), (550, 50, 500, 500))  # right side player ships and enemy hit

    pygame.draw.rect(win, shipfinalcolour, (ship1smallx, ship1smally, 50, 50))  # enemy first ship blends in
    pygame.draw.rect(win, shipfinalcolour, (ship2mediumx, ship2mediumy, 50, 100))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, shipfinalcolour, (ship3largex, ship3largey, 50, 150) )
    pygame.draw.rect(win, shipfinalcolour, (ship4largex,ship4largey,150, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, shipfinalcolour, (ship5mediumx,ship5mediumy, 100, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, shipfinalcolour, (ship6smallx,ship6smally, 50, 50))

    pygame.draw.rect(win, black, ((mouse[0] // 50) * 50, (mouse[1] // 50) * 50, 50, 50))  # using mouse create ships

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, black, (mouse[0]//50 * 50 + 50, mouse[1] // 50 *50,50, 50))
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, black, (mouse[0]//50 * 50 - 50, mouse[1]// 50 * 50, 50, 50))
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, black, (mouse[0]// 50 * 50, mouse[1]//50 * 50 - 50, 50 , 50))
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, black, (mouse[0]//50*50, mouse[1]//50 *50 +50, 50, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, black,(hitcoorx[x], hitcoory[y], 50, 50))  # player hit selector moves by 50 pixels eachtime is 50x50

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        new_variablex = x
        new_variabley = y

        if enemyship_listx[new_variablex] == ship1smallx and enemyship_listy[new_variabley] == ship1smally:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (hitcoorx[new_variablex], hitcoory[new_variabley], 50, 50))

        elif enemyship_listx[new_variablex] == ship2mediumx and enemyship_listy[new_variabley] == ship2mediumy:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (hitcoorx[new_variablex], hitcoory[new_variabley], 50, 50))

        elif enemyship_listx[new_variablex] == ship2mediumx and enemyship_listy[new_variabley] == ship2mediumy + 50:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (hitcoorx[new_variablex], hitcoory[new_variabley], 50, 50))

        elif enemyship_listx[new_variablex] == ship3largex and enemyship_listy[new_variabley] == ship3largey:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (hitcoorx[new_variablex], hitcoory[new_variabley], 50, 50))

        elif enemyship_listx[new_variablex] == ship3largex and enemyship_listy[new_variabley] == ship3largey + 50:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (hitcoorx[new_variablex], hitcoory[new_variabley], 50, 50))

        elif enemyship_listx[new_variablex] == ship3largex and enemyship_listy[new_variabley] == ship3largey + 100:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (hitcoorx[new_variablex], hitcoory[new_variabley], 50, 50))

        elif enemyship_listx[new_variablex] == ship4largex and enemyship_listy[new_variabley] == ship4largey:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (hitcoorx[new_variablex], hitcoory[new_variabley], 50, 50))

        elif enemyship_listx[new_variablex] == ship4largex + 50 and enemyship_listy[new_variabley] == ship4largey:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (hitcoorx[new_variablex], hitcoory[new_variabley], 50, 50))

        elif enemyship_listx[new_variablex] == ship4largex + 100 and enemyship_listy[new_variabley] == ship4largey:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (hitcoorx[new_variablex], hitcoory[new_variabley], 50, 50))

        elif enemyship_listx[new_variablex] == ship5mediumx and enemyship_listy[new_variabley] == ship5mediumy:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (hitcoorx[new_variablex], hitcoory[new_variabley], 50, 50))

        elif enemyship_listx[new_variablex] == ship5mediumx + 50 and enemyship_listy[new_variabley] == ship5mediumy:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (hitcoorx[new_variablex], hitcoory[new_variabley], 50, 50))

        elif enemyship_listx[new_variablex] == ship6smallx and enemyship_listy[new_variabley] == ship6smally:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (hitcoorx[new_variablex], hitcoory[new_variabley], 50, 50))

        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, red, (hitcoorx[new_variablex], hitcoory[new_variabley], 50, 50))

    for i in range(50,551,50):   # grid system for left side
        pygame.draw.line(win, black, (i,50), (i,550), 5)
        pygame.draw.line(win, black, (50,i), (550,i), 5)

    win.blit(textsurface1, (400, 65))
    win.blit(textsurface2, (875, 65))
    win.blit(textsurface3, (75, 10))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Please consider creating a [mcve] to make it easier for people to help you. Seems like you need to change the way you manage your game state. Typically you should initialise your game state, handle events to modify the state, render the state and then update the display.

Answer (score 0):

If the questions is about this:"I cannot seem to make the changes permanent"

Then you need to store infos about  this into data file.

You can start with a text file (or use the shelve python module).
This python module has a function called shelve.open() that returns a "shelf file object" that can be used to create, read, and write data to shelf files on the hard drive.
You can use any python module ( example: sqlite for databases way).

Just create a new hit_coord_xy and save this coord every time press a key to file:

NOTE: Using hitcoorx and hitcoory is not very good for store data (is more fast on testing or debugging projects ) I use one function/method (object) for each press key and solve it, let's see one simple example:

```
if keys[pygame.K_a] and x>0:
    x = x - 1
    y =0
    hit_air = true
    hit_water = false
    hitcoord_point[x, y, hit_air, hit_water]
```

and solve like this:

if x,y is into hitcoorx , hitcoory , hit_air is true them the enemy is hit from air with a air_damage ...

You need to create one structure data with coord and values for hit/ non hit, hit_water, hit_air, maybe number of hits etc.

Each object from game will allow to use this data to show hits , score and make changes into the game .

Your code is simple but you can use class for each objects like for example: players, maps. The main reason the source code will be short and easy to maintain.

Comment: I believe Cormac is asking about maintaining game state during execution, rather that storing such state in the file system.

Comment: about default code : the maintaining game state during execution is not good with just if else , the good part of code start with the lists...